# How to create a webpart with a picture and some lines of text

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part

I am using SharePoint 2010 Standard edition and on my home page I want to create a webpart which includes a picture on top and under the picture a 10 lines message. Dont know which webpart type I should choose.

Since its the text for president so a designated person will change the text and on clicking on the webpart only that person will be able to change the text.

Thanks

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Content Editor WebPart is your best bet.

[SharePoint Tutorial: How to work with the content editor web part](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-tutorials/2007/web-parts/content-editor/)